# Are there any computers that could fit inside a standard North American power outlet box?

Tags: computer-building, raspberry-pi

I would like to be able to put a computer in the wall. With decent-performing boards as small as the Raspberry Pi, has anyone ever attempted to put one inside of a power box? If so, which ones and how did you wire up the power itself?

Here is the kind of box I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: I would be mindful of the heat that could potentially be generated by something like this. Make sure there's no risk of a fire!

Comment: There were some mini linux systems that fit in a standard electrical outlet but this was years ago, [Guruplug is about the only one](http://www.plugcomputer.org/) that is currently available that I can find, but does not fit in the box. [Also see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug)

Comment: I think the problem here is that while something like a Raspberry Pi might fit, if you're thinking about wiring it directly to the mains, you need somewhere for the power adapter to go and that's hard to shrink.  You could put the whole thing BEHIND the wall socket but that's cheating.  Now, I've seen small boxes that plug INTO the power outlet...  EDIT: Like what Moab just posted.

Comment: I don't think the Pi will quite fit unless you remove/bend the connectors on the ends.  It appears to be about 11cm long with connectors, which is about 4.33.  A standard box is 4-9/16 (4.56) on the *outside*, but you must subtract at least 0.25" from that for the wall thickness of the box.

Comment: You can, however, get larger boxes with a "mud ring" to reduce the visible size down to the standard 2x4.  Of course, access would be a b!tch.

Comment: @DarthAndroid - One advantage to the outlet box is that it's been tested to be essentially fireproof.

Comment: @DanielRHicks And yet they are the source of more than [5300 fires](http://www.rmu.net/rmu-tips/home-electrical-fires-statistics-tips.html) every year. I'm not saying a Raspberry Pi is going to cause a fire (and would be surprised if it did), just to be mindful of having electronics in enclosed spaces with no ventilation, especially if a user is going to be hooking into the mains of their house. :)

Comment: @DarthAndroid - The source of the fires (and you're off by 10x) isn't the box, but rather the high current flowing through it.  Or, all too often, connections in no box at all, or overheated extension cords, etc.  The box is designed to contain the damage from an overheating connection, or sparks from arcing, but it can't protect from jackleg wiring, pennies in fuse boxes, space heaters on lamp extension cords, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ChipPC products](http://www.chippc.com/thin-clients/jack-pc/index.asp)

[Tom's hardware write up](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Chip-PC-Jack-PC-Disk-on-Chip-Alchemy-Au-Windows-CE,11573.html)

.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard North American power outlet box.

Comment: @martineau, that is a 4x4 box with a custom faceplate installed on the front to provide the necessary connections.  In thoery, one could utilize this for initial set-up of the server and then remove and replace the cover.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of any full computer systems that can entirely fit within such a box (unless you want to talk about cell phones, which could conceivably be used as a low power computer) there are several very small, thin computer systems out there. What you could do is use the outlet box as a terminal for any outwards facing connections (usb, dvi) and put the rest of the computer directly underneath the box inside the wall itself.

Here's the smallest computer I could find: http://www.thebookpc.com/product_info.php/cPath/68_91/products_id/485

Answer (score 0):

I think you could pretty easily fit one of the new Android PCs that are shaped like a USB thumb drive in an outlet box without too much trouble. The [AllWinner A10](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/05/new-74-android-mini-computer-is-slightly-larger-than-a-thumb-drive/), for example, would fit. Have a look also at Miniand Tech's [MK802](https://www.miniand.com/products/MK802%20Android%20Mini%20PC) and the [UG802](http://liliputing.com/2012/08/this-is-what-those-new-rk3066-android-4-0-mini-pcs-look-like.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think a [gumstix](https://www.gumstix.com/) board would be small enough, but you would need to fit a power supply as well.

[image]

```
Length   11.0 cm (4.3 inches)
Width    4.4 cm (1.73 inches)
Height   1.8 cm (0.71 inches)
```